# How to apply appropriate costs to ranked choices

Tags: java, arraylist, ranking

I have a list of 4 activity choices

```
Activities
Activity 1
Activity 2
Activity 3
Activity 4
```

And I have a list of people who have chosen 4 activities ranked in order e.g.

```
Person    Choices (1st,2nd,3rd,4th)
Person 1  2,3,1,4
Person 2  3,1,4,2
...
```

I am trying to allocate costs to the ranked choices based on their position and was just wondering how I could do it.
An example is Person 1, whose 1st choice is activity 2 and the cost for this is 1. Their 2nd choice is activity 3 and the cost is 2 because it is in position 2 and so on. 
I am adding these costs to a lists because I need this cost list later in its same order.

Code I've tried

```
List<Integer> cost = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(Person p: people){
 for (int i = 0; i < p.getChoices().size(); i++) {

  cost.add(p.getChoices(i+1);
 }
}
```

Just some extra context
The cost list will then be used to populate a transportation problem grid, where the sources are represented by the activity as seen below. The sources in the grid are in fixed positions, so when looking at person 1. Activity 2 was their 1st choice, Activity 3 their 2nd, Activity 1 their 3rd and Activity 4 their 4th.

```
  Person 1 | Person2 | Person n
1     3         2
2     1         4
3     2         1
4     4         3
```

I keep getting confused on how to apply this as it should be simple. In my previous implementations I end up with just a cost list of 1,2,3,4 continuously. I cannot wrap my head around the theory for some reason (probs because its 5am XD). 
I am open to any theory or pseudocode. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am open to you showing what you have tried so far

Comment: It's such a small thing but it's stopping me from integrating other more complex bits of my code into my software :(

Comment: Thank you! I'll edit code into the question. Give me a sec.

Comment: @Scary Wombat It's really basic (the code that I've added). If it's quick and easy for you, I would appreciate the help. But it's probs best if go to bed and try again in the day time

Comment: Your code will not compile, but maybe you want `cost.add(s.getChoices.get(i));`

Comment: sleep tight ;-)

Comment: Tried it it just prints out what's already there e.g. 2,3,1,4. Thank you though for taking a look! Night night xx

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, it looks like you want to create a list with the values of each of the people, maintaining order in sets of 4, and the code you have should do that?

Comment: Have you corrected this line? `cost.add(p.getChoices(i+1);`

Comment: @TranNgocKhoa yeah I corrected thanks

Comment: So, does it work?

Comment: Unfortunately not the i+1 gives it an IndexOutofBoundsException

Comment: The cost list will be used to populate a transportation problem grid, so the Activity will actually represent sources 1-4, so they are fixed positions on the grid. I will update the question to try and show what I mean. I'm just wondering if there is a mathematical way to solve this question rather than having to reorder the choices and apply costs before adding to the cost list.

Comment: Have you noticed that person 2 has two 1s, and no 2?

Comment: How about `for (int i = 0; i < p.getChoices().size() - 1; i++) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cost of an activity for a person is its position in the choices, you can declare a method `costOf` in class Person:

```
public class Person {
    private final List<Integer> choices = new ArrayList<>();

    public Person(Integer... choices) {
        this.choices.addAll(Arrays.asList(choices));
    }

    public List<Integer> getChoices() {
       return choices;
    }

    public int costOf(Integer activity) {
        return choices.indexOf(activity)+1;
    }
}
```

To print the grid, you would do that:

```
    List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
                new Person(2,3,1,4),
                new Person(3,1,4,1)
            );
    // Print grid
    for (int activity = 1; activity <= 4; ++activity) {
        System.out.print(activity);
        for (Person p: persons) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(p.costOf(activity));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This will print:

```
1 3 2
2 1 0
3 2 1
4 4 3
```

You can see that there is a zero because the second person has no 2 in its choices.

Assuming it's a typo, and you replace the second 1 with 2, you get:

```
1 3 2
2 1 4
3 2 1
4 4 3
```

What was expected.

Comment: Yeah sorry for the typo. This is it! Thank you very much for your help and time!

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing a sample code. I've written a code for you as per my understanding of your question.

Person Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Person {
    ArrayList<Integer> choices = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Integer> getChoices() {
       return choices;
    }

    public void setChoices(ArrayList<Integer> choices) {
       this.choices = choices;
    }
}
```

Main Method

```
public class MainMethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Person person1 = new Person();
       ArrayList<Integer> activity1 = new ArrayList<>();
       activity1.add(2);
       activity1.add(3);
       activity1.add(1);
       activity1.add(4);
       person1.setChoices(activity1);

       Person person2 = new Person();
       ArrayList<Integer> activity2 = new ArrayList<>();
       activity2.add(2);
       activity2.add(4);
       activity2.add(1);
       activity2.add(3);
       person2.setChoices(activity2);

       Person person3 = new Person();
       ArrayList<Integer> activity3 = new ArrayList<>();
       activity3.add(1);
       activity3.add(3);
       activity3.add(4);
       activity3.add(2);
       person3.setChoices(activity3);

       Person person4 = new Person();
       ArrayList<Integer> activity4 = new ArrayList<>();
       activity4.add(4);
       activity4.add(3);
       activity4.add(1);
       activity4.add(4);
       person4.setChoices(activity4);

       ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
       persons.add(person1);
       persons.add(person2);
       persons.add(person3);
       persons.add(person4);

       int i = 1;
       for(Person person :persons) {
           System.out.println("Person"+i);
           //List
           person.getChoices().forEach(System.out::println);
           i++;
       }
       System.out.println("**********************");
       //If you need cost list. I gave you option to store in list as well.
       int j = 1;
       for(Person person :persons) {
        System.out.println("Person"+j);
        ArrayList<Integer> cost = person.getChoices();
        cost.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        i++;
       }
   }
}
```

If your requirement is different, please elaborate and let me know.

Comment: This also works too! Thank you very much for your help Yanish!